# Search for words in a ArrayList<String> and save result to Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, pattern-matching

I have some words in a `List<String>` and I want to iterate inside an `ArrayList<String>`, searching for matches and putting each of them (with their occurrences) in a `Map<String, Integer>`. I write this method:

```
public Map<String, Integer> findTheWords(ArrayList<String> textInFiles, List<String> words) {


        for (int i = 0; i < textInFiles.size(); i++) {

            Map<String, Integer> mapResult = new HashMap<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {

                    int count = 0;

                    Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\b" + words.get(j) + "\\b");
                    Matcher matcher = regexp.matcher(textInFiles.get(i));

                     if(matcher.find()) {
                         while (matcher.find()) {
                            count++;
                        }

                        mapResult.put(textInFiles.get(i), count);
                     }

            }
        }

    return mapResult;               
    }
```

Problem is with `count` variable and inserting right value in the map

Comment: *"Problem is with count variable and inserting right value in the map"*. Can you please be more explicit about what you expect and how what you get is different ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `matcher.find()`, you're consuming an occurrence.

You have two solutions:

1) adding one when inserting, which isn't really clean and readable

2) test before you insert

```
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
     count++;
}
if (n>0) mapResult.put(textInFiles.get(i), count);
```